# How to validate incoming data is an array and it contains decimal number using firestore security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My client app is sending location data to firestore so i wanna make sure it is in decimal formate if not then not allow to write.

I have it like this,
Collection **place** and document in random number and feild as **loc** : [0]:7.8 , [1]:2.7

Answer (score 0):

This currently isn't possible with security rules, as it provides no mechanism for you to iterate a list and check each item in it.

If you want to check if a single value is a number, you can simply check that the client provided a number type value using `value is number`.  So you could check if a known field is a number:

```
allow write: if request.resource.data.knownField is number;
```

But you won't be able to do that for every item in a list.  You will need a backend to do that.

Comment: But I'm wondering how to use latlng method mentioned here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.latlng_

Comment: I don't think that's going to help you here.  If you have another question about that, please post it separately.